# Delete duplicate lines, with partial match

Tags: deletion, lines

Sample text:

```
This is first line.a
This is over_second line.
This is over_fourth line.
This is third line.
This is over_fourth delete it.
This is over_fourth and one more.
This is over_second with another text.
```

Need to delete lines where partial match occur, i.e if over_second occurs in another line, then whole line should get deleted. So output will be as follows;

```
This is first line.
This is over_second line.
This is third line.
This is over_fourth line.
```

I could only come up with: `over_\w+` for selecting section of text. But don't know how to recognize duplicates, and delete whole line.

Comment: Is the requirement "for each specific match for the regexp, retain only the first line in the buffer containing that text" ?

Comment: Yes. Line with first instance of match should be preserved, while subsequent matches or remaining matches should get deleted.

Comment: Once this process gets complete for over_second, same should be repeated for over_fourth.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try `delete-duplicate-lines`, which is part of distributed Emacs.
2. Emacs Wiki page [Duplicate Lines](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DuplicateLines) might help.

   - It points to a [blog post](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/03/01/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-delete-duplicate-lines/) about it.
   - It explains why interactive search-and-replace might not help.
   - It explains how to do it with Lisp, in various ways.
   - It explains how to do it with the UNIX / GNU/Linux command `sort` or `unique`.

Comment: These are good suggestions, but OP was asking about deleting *partial duplicates*, i.e., lines that contain the same string, but aren't full duplicates of each other. I don't think delete-duplicate-lines does that?

Comment: @Tyler: Oh, right. Maybe the other stuff on that page will help in some way...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do this all the time, the quickest solution might be using interactive replacement: `query-replace-regexp`, bound to `C-M-%`. Start with point at the top of the buffer.

Note, if you want to delete entire lines, you'll need to include a newline in your regexp. You enter this at the prompt with `C-q C-j`.

So, for `over_second`, call `C-M-%`, then enter the regular expression:

```
C-qC-j.*over_second.*
```

This will match an entire line that contains the string `over_second`, and includes the previous new line.

Then enter the empty string (just type `<enter>`) for the replacement value.

The first line that matches the regexp should now be highlighted. This is the one you want to **keep**, so type `n` to tell Emacs to skip it. The next line will be highlighted. You can delete this by typing `y` (or `<space>`).

You can keep typing `y` until all the matches are deleted, or you can type `!` to delete all remaining matches at once.

Answer (score 0):

I could swear this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Try this:

```el
(defun my-delete-duplicate-matches (regexp)
  "Delete matching lines, except the first instance of each specific match."
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (save-restriction
    (when (use-region-p)
      (narrow-to-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((matches (make-hash-table :test #'equal)))
        (save-match-data
          (while (re-search-forward regexp nil :noerror)
            (if (not (gethash (match-string 0) matches))
                (puthash (match-string 0) t matches)
              (forward-line 0)
              (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-line 1)
                                            (point))))))))))
```

Caveats:

- If the same matching text appears twice on the first line in which it is found, the line will be deleted.
- More generally, if a line contains both the first instance of a given match, and a repeat instance of an earlier match, the line will be deleted.
- Multi-line patterns are not supported.